# How to measure characteristics of file (hard-disk) I/O?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io

How to measure characteristics of file (hard-disk) I/O? For example on a machine with a hard-disk (with speed X) and a cpu i7 (or whatever number of cores) and Y amount of ram (with Z Hz BIOS) what would be (on Windows OS):

- Optimum number of files that can be written to the HD in parallel?
- Optimum number of files that can be read from HD in parallel?
- Facilities of file-system helping faster writings. (Like: Is there a feature or tool there that let you write batches of binary data on different sectors (or hards) and then bind them as a file? I do not know much about underlying file I/O in OS. But it would be reasonable to have such tools!)
- If there are such tools as part before, are there in .NET too?

I want to write large files (streamed over the web or another source) as fast (and as parallel) as possible! I am coding this in C#. And it acts like a download manager; so if streaming got interrupted, it can carry on later.

Answer (score 3):

The answer (as so often) depends on your usage. The whole operating system is one big tradeoff between different use scenarios. For the NTFS filesystem one could mention block size set to 4k, NTFS storing files less than block size in MTF, size of files, number of files, fragmentation, etc.

If you are planning to write large files then a block size of 64k may be good. That is if you plan to read large amounts of data. If you read smaller amounts of data then smaller sizes are good. The OS works in 4k pages, so 4k is good. Compression (and encryption?) as well as SQL and Exchange only work on 4k pages (iirc).

If you write small files (<4k)they will be stored inside the MFT so you don't have to make "an ekstra jump". This is especially useful in write operations (read may have MFT cached). MFT stores files in sequences (i.e. blocks 1000-1010,2000-2010) so fragmentation will make the MFT bigger. Writing files to disk in parallell is one of the main causes to fragmentation, the other is deleting files. You may pre-allocate the required size for a file and Windows will try to find a suitable place on the disk to counter fragmentation. There are also real-time defragmentation programs like [O&O Defrag](http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/).

Windows maps a binarystream pretty much directly to the physical location on the disk, so using different read/write methods will not yield as much performance boost as other factors. For maximum speed programs use technieue for direct memory mapping to disk. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

There is an option in Windows (under Device Manager, Harddisks) to increase caching on the disk. This is dangerous as ut could damage the filesystem if the computer bluescreens or looses power, but gives a big performance boost on writing smaller files (and on all writes). If the disk is busy this is especially valuable as the seek-time will decrease. Windows use what is called the elevator algorithm which basically means it moves the harddisk heads over the surface back and forth serving any application in the direction it is moving.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! I want to write large files (streamed over the web or another source) as fast (and as parallel) as possible! I am coding this in C#.